# Yii2 : kartik Select2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, jquery-select2

I have 2 select2 dropdownlist  the second depends on data from the first one

the first one code :

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'patient_id')->widget(select2::className(),[
   'data'=>  arrayhelper::map(patient::find()->all(),'patient_id','patient_name'),
   'options'=>['placeholder'=>'select patient Name ... '],
   'pluginOptions'=>[
            'allowClear'=>true
   ],
])?>
```

the second one code :

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'doctor_id')->widget(select2::className(),[
   'data'=>  arrayhelper::map(doctors::find()->all(),'doctor_id','doctor_name'),
   'options'=>['placeholder'=>'أختر اسم الطبيب '],
   'pluginOptions'=>[
            'allowClear'=>true
   ],
])?>
```

i know the sql code in the second one is :

> select doctor_name from doctors

so i need it to be :

> SELECT DISTINCT doctor_name from doctors where doctor_id in (SELECT doctor_id from patient_services  WHERE patient_id="THE VALUE FROM THE 1st DROPDOWNLIST" )

in the regular dropdownlist it work by like this way [Yii2 Lesson - 20 Dependent Drop Down Lists By DoingITeasyChannel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZepxKw8VA7w)  but in select2 i didn't find how to do it .

------------------------------- after update ----
as the comments there is DepDrop but i got confused how to use it.

i've changed

`<?= $form->field($model, 'patient_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(patient::find()->asArray()->all(), 'patient_id', 'patient_name')]);
?>`

and the other one is :

`<?= $form->field($model, 'doctor_id')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select ...'],
    'type' => DepDrop::TYPE_SELECT2,
    'select2Options'=>['pluginOptions'=>['allowClear'=>true]],
    'pluginOptions'=>[
        'depends'=>['receipts-doctor_id'], // here i got confused 
        'url' => Url::to(['/receipts/child']),
        'loadingText' => 'Loading child level 1 ...',
    ]
]);
?>`

in controller

`public function actionChild() {
    $out = [];
    if (isset($_POST['depdrop_parents'])) { // what they meaning by depdrop_parents or what i should change it  ?

        $id = end($_POST['depdrop_parents']);
        $list = Account::find()->andWhere(['parent'=>$id])->asArray()->all();
        $selected  = null;
        if ($id != null && count($list) > 0) {
            $selected = '';
            foreach ($list as $i => $account) {
                $out[] = ['id' => $account['id'], 'name' => $account['name']];
                if ($i == 0) {
                    $selected = $account['id'];
                }
            }
            // Shows how you can preselect a value
            echo Json::encode(['output' => $out, 'selected'=>$selected]);
            return;
        }
    }
    echo Json::encode(['output' => '', 'selected'=>'']);
}`

Comment: You can use [Kartik DepDrop](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop)

Comment: To add to what @InsaneSkull suggested you can use the DepDrop plugin and still use Select2 because the DepDrop plugin has support for Select2 dropdowns. You have to use the `type` option.

Comment: @InsaneSkull  Thank you ..  i didn't see this before ,,, i saw it and i have some issues `'depends'=>['account-lev0'],` i didn't get it  i have the parent id is `patient_id`  and there is something else i got confused in controller code `$list =Account::find()->andWhere(['parent'=>$id])->asArray()->all();`

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas i got confused how to use it . I will update my question

Comment: Ok, so I see you have written Select2 and Depdrop. It looks fine (at first at least). Where you're stuck?

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas i wrote some comments in my Question , i got confused here ` 'depends'=>['account-lev0'],` what they meaning by `account-lev0` or what i should change it  and in controller code `if (isset($_POST['depdrop_parents'])) `   what they meaning by depdrop_parents or what i should change it  ?

Comment: I have provided more details in my answer. If there are still questions left (or something else fails), add a comment or provide more details. :)

Answer (score 0):

First field (Select2):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'patient_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(patient::find()->asArray()->all(), 'patient_id', 'patient_name')]);
?>
```

Second field (DepDrop):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'doctor_id')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select ...'],
    'type' => DepDrop::TYPE_SELECT2,
    'select2Options'=> ['pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true]],
    'pluginOptions'=> [
        'depends' => ['receipts-doctor_id'],
        'url' => Url::to(['/receipts/child']),
        'loadingText' => 'Loading child level 1 ...',
    ]
]);
?>
```

Plugin option `'depends' => ['receipts-doctor_id'],` shows which element (takes element's ID) must be changed (on click, on select, etc.) in order to send Ajax request and retrieve results from controller. In this case, an element with ID `receipts-doctor_id` should be present. If you don't know or you want to set ID for parent element, you can use `'options' => ['id' => 'receipts-doctor_id'],` for your parent element.

And for controller, you can retrieve value like this:

```
public function actionChild()
{
    $depdropParents = Yii::$app->request->post('depdrop_parents');

    if ($depdropParents !== null) {
        $value = $depdropParents[0];
        // Now your $value contains what was being selected in parent element
    }
}
```

Comment: there is something not clear . there is nothing happening in after i select the first dropdownlist  .. and the second  DepDrop still disable !

Comment: If so, then it means there is an error at controller (backend code). Use networking (if you know how to) to see error message.